# Link-Local Connection to Device Not Working

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am trying to connect to a device over link-local via IPv4. I've done my best to configure the GigE port correctly.

[image]

- When I turn the device on, the Ubuntu (12.10) gui pops up an icon saying I'm connected to the device.

[image: Connection]

- `ifconfig` shows the following for `eth1`:

  ```
  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:a4:4c:22:17:08  
  inet addr:169.254.148.88  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:100  Metric:1
  RX packets:559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:2033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:193414 (193.4 KB)  TX bytes:203089 (203.0 KB)
  Interrupt:18 Memory:f7900000-f7920000
  ```

I have vendor supplied software that will automatically recognize the device when I run it. Without going into the details, it is basically just a C++ executable that is meant to demo the provided SDK by finding a device and working with it. I don't think it is a problem with the code. The SDK is made for linux, but their tech help is pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu and thinks its just a problem with how I am setting up the connection.

- Furthermore, I have connected this device to the same machine, same GigE port, while booted into Windows, and it is recognized instantly. The connection is shown here:

[image]

I took the netmask and ip address from Windows and used `ifonfig eth1 $IP netmask $netmask` to get them to match. I don't much like this method, as eventually this will have to work on a computer without an Ubuntu GUI or a Windows partition.

- When I tail the `dmesg` logs, I see that the connection is detected, but I get this message:

  ```
  [ 4174.533981] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Down
  [ 4180.212770] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
  [ 4180.216769] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
  [ 4180.216772] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
  [ 4180.216929] netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
  ```

I am fairly new to Linux, and very new to networking. But I've been banging my head against this problem and making no headway. Does anyone know anything about link-local, or the attribute parsing error that could give me some suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by this *But my software cannot recognize it. The software is vendor supplied, as well as my own.*?   Could you give some details about the device & software you are talking about?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: What is the IP address and netmask you use in Windows?  What is the IP address of the device?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a screenshot of the Windows network configuration.

Comment: You can't connect to a device when you configure the interface for local--that is for local (the device itself, and no others, also known as 127.0.0.1, or the loopback) testing purposes only.

To connect to the device, use a static or DHCP assigned address.

Comment: Maybe your windows machine is using a different packetsize (MTU) than Linux. According to your information the MTU on your Ubuntu computer is 100 (while 1500 is more reasonable) Do you have any information about the MTU size on your Windows computer ?

Comment: I think their pretty inexperienced tech is correct, thinking that the 'pretty inexperienced' customer isn't configuring the connection correctly ;)

Comment: On the Windows machine, open a command prompt and run: netstat This will show you the IP addresses and ports of any connected devices. Verify that the device is using a 169.254.x.x address, and then follow the instructions provided by conman253.

Answer (score 2):

It appears your network settings are mis-configured.  RGS's comment is correct: by selecting a local link, you are ensuring a network connection will not work.  The IP address you've displayed that automatically works, is in the APIPA range.  This is not the drone you seek...I mean connection.  
http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/

All you should need to do for a wired connection is plug it into the computer; Ubuntu does the rest. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wired-connect.html

If you are trying to connect 2 computers directly to each other, I would recommend assigning a "static IP address" to the Ubuntu machine: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html

In that case, give the Ubuntu Machine the following settings:

```
IP Address: 169.254.146.89
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway: 169.254.146.88 (or whatever it says for IP Address in the window of that print screen you posted, the point being for it to find the windows machine by it's IP Address)
```

To access your network settings:

```
1. From the Dash Home (Ubuntu start menu, also accessed by hitting the windows key)
   type network and hit Enter.
2. Select Wired/Wireless and turn it On.
```

You listed some very detailed information, which is good.  You did not give enough basic information though, such as:

```
1. How you are connecting: via a router, switch, modem, or directly to another computer.
2. Your desired network setup: DHCP, static, APIPA.
3. How many and what kind of devices you want to connect.
```

Ubuntu has some documentation aimed at walking you through setup.  Please read that before posting a question in the future. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/index.html